# How to import data to Amazon S3 from URL

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and the URL of a large file. I would like to store the content located at the URL in the S3 bucket.

I could download the file to my local machine and then upload it to S3 with Cloudberry or Jungledisk or whatever. However, if the file is large, this may take a long time because the file must be transferred twice, and my network connection is much slower than Amazon's.

If I have a lot of data to store in S3, I can start an EC2 instance, retrieve the files to the instance with curl or wget, and then push the data from the EC2 instance to S3. This works, but it's a lot of steps if I just want to archive one file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any way that you can do this without the step of having the file locally simply because of the way that Amazon S3 is done, you post data to it, it doesn't go grab data.

Answer (score 2):

I know that is this an old questions but I am answering incase someone still interested.
At my company we just release a new website which has many options to transfer files between cloud services.
One of these features may help you do what you want without downloading the file to your computer, it will go direct from the URL to amazon S3, The website will just need the full file URL such as www.example.com/files/my.jpg .
Website URL: http://www.autofilemove.com
http://www.autofilemove.com/Support/Features  check Web Url feature